# Getting grid-column when farther down the tree

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm integrating a working CSS design into my angular application.  The design uses grid and grid-column quite successfully, something like this:

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(50px, auto);
    grid-gap: 36px 20px;
    margin: 0;
}

.single {
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.double {
    grid-column: 2 / span 2;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="single">a</div>
    <div class="double">b</div>
</div>
```

My problem is that this is going into an Angular app, and by default Angular ends up putting tags on the page for your components, which interrupts the HTML.  So my actual HTMl looks something like this (the spans are placeholders for the tags that Angular puts in for my components):

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(50px, auto);
    grid-gap: 36px 20px;
    margin: 0;
}

.single {
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.double {
    grid-column: 2 / span 2;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <span>
        <span>
            <div class="single">a</div>
        </span>
    </span>
    <span>
        <span>
            <div class="double">b</div>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Now I know I can fix this by making adjustments in angular, which is what I normally do - convert components to use attribute selectors so they can go directly on a normal tag, use ng-container where possible, apply host css rules, etc...

However, all the rest of the CSS is designed in such a way that it doesn't mind some extra tags hanging out in the tree, so in an attempt to keep things consistent, I'm wondering if there is a way to do this **without** adjusting my tag structure.  However I'm not super-familiar with these CSS directives, and haven't managed to do it myself.  Therefore I've come here to ask:

#### Is there a way to tell the CSS grid/grid-column properties to effectively ignore the presence of some extra tags in the DOM tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the style to direct childs and it will always work with or without extra tags:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(50px, auto);
  grid-gap: 36px 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

.grid> :first-child {
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.grid> :last-child {
  grid-column: 2 / span 2;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <span>
        <span>
            <div class="single">a</div>
        </span>
  </span>
  <span>
        <span>
            <div class="double">b</div>
        </span>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="single">a</div>

  <div class="double">b</div>

</div>
```

Or use `display:contents` if you want to ignore some tags. Simply pay attention to the support: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(50px, auto);
  grid-gap: 36px 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

.single {
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.double {
  grid-column: 2 / span 2;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.grid span {
  display:contents;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <span>
        <span>
            <div class="single">a</div>
        </span>
  </span>
  <span>
        <span>
            <div class="double">b</div>
        </span>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="single">a</div>

  <div class="double">b</div>

</div>
```

Comment: `display: contents` worked perfectly and was far quicker than making appropriate adjustments in Angular.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the `grid-area` attribute to better control what elements are understood to be parts of the grid.

[Here's a fiddle you can try](https://jsfiddle.net/tripathiakshit/18m0ouvr/)

Comment: the area aren't working, remove them and you will have the same result. It's working because you defined grid-template-columns

Comment: Oh okay! Thanks!